# How to convert into cyrillic

Tags: java, string, type-conversion, decode

Good day.

I got string like this from server

```
\u041a\u0438\u0441\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0432 \u0410\u043d\u0434\u0440\u0435\u0439
```

I need to convert it into cyrillic cp-1251 string.

How do i do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is a literal sequence of characters that must decoded, you'll need to first start with something like this (assuming your input is in the string *input*):

```
StringBuffer decodedInput = new StringBuffer();
Matcher match = Pattern.compile("\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})| ").matcher(input);
while (match.find()) {
  String character = match.group(1);
  if (character == null)
    decodedInput.append(match.group());
  else
    decodedInput.append((char)Integer.parseInt(character, 16));
}
```

At this point, you should have java string representation of your input in *decodedInput*.

If your system supports the cp-1251 charset, you can then convert that to cp-1251 with something like this:

```
Charset cp1251charset = Charset.forName("cp-1251");
ByteBuffer output = cp1251charset.encode(decodedInput.toString());
```

Comment: It didn`t help. Charset converts every character of input string into byte. So \u041a converted into 6 bytes, but it must be converted into 2 bytes 04+1a.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was a java string representation you were showing - I didn't realise it was a literal sequence of characters. Have updated my answer.

Comment: Wow. It`s so weird - such a simple task needs sich a complex trick. Thank you - you made my day...